# Why is there no GT-entry in my .vcf file from bacteria

Tags: variant-calling

I mapped raw reads obtained from an E. coli genome (.fastq file) to my reference genome. Next, I exported the .vcf (variant calling file), which looks something like the header example shown below (total >50 lines):

```
#CHROM  POS ID  REF ALT QUAL    FILTER  INFO    FORMAT  Variants:_LGC19-XL01_S63_L001_R_001_(trimmed)
CFC381_K12_Bw25113  360287  .   GGGAAT  AATTCC  1952.76 .   NS=1;VF=0.380;SB=0.533;SB50=0.60;SB65=1.0;TYPE=Substitution;AVQUAL=30   DP:AO   231:89
```

**How can I back-fill or quickly assign the missing GTs to the `.vcf` ?**

For my downstream process (`plink --pca`, via `bfctools merge`), I need that there are GT entries in every `.vcf`, so I can merge them and the respective GT is shown in the merged `.vcf`. I only found solutions that need the `.bam` file, but that is laborious and I don't think I need the `.bam` in the case of haploid data.

- This method needs `.bam`: https://www.biostars.org/p/319304/
- This method needs `.fastq`: https://training.galaxyproject.org/training-material/topics/variant-analysis/tutorials/non-dip/tutorial.html#examining-the-results

However, the`.fastq` is actually from a mixed culture, so I wonder do I really need to follow the `.bam`-strategy? Suggestion for a tool? But in that case, why did it not export the GTs in the fist place (I exported from "geneious" sequence analysis program)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The representation for a variant present in a haploid genome should be `1`. A heterozygote in a diploid genome would be `0/1` (or `0|1` or `1|0`  if phased). So, to add a `1` as the genotype, you would need to first insert a `GT` to the beginning of each INFO line and then the `1` at the beginning of the last field. But, this should happen only on lines that are not headers (do not start with `#`). This should do it:

```
$ awk -F'\t' -v OFS="\t" '{ if(/^#/){print}else{$9="GT:"$9;$10="1:"$10;print}}' file.vcf 
#CHROM  POS ID  REF ALT QUAL    FILTER  INFO    FORMAT  Variants:_LGC19-XL01_S63_L001_R_001_(trimmed)
CFC381_K12_Bw25113  360287  .   GGGAAT  AATTCC  1952.76 .   NS=1;VF=0.380;SB=0.533;SB50=0.60;SB65=1.0;TYPE=Substitution;AVQUAL=30   GT:DP:AO    1:231:89
```

So just redirect the output to a fixed file:

```
$ awk -F'\t' -v OFS="\t" '{ if(/^#/){print}else{$9="GT:"$9;$10="1:"$10;print}}' file.vcf > fixed.vcf
```

Now, in this specific case, you could also do something like this:

```
$ sed -i.bak '/^[^#]/{s/\<DP:AO\t/GT:DP:AO\t1:/}' file.vcf
```

But that assumes that all lines will have the exact same INFO field of `DP:AO` which is not a safe assumption since each variant can have different INFO fields.

Comment: Perfect! It worked super good, I am so grateful to both of you!
So one thing has gotten forgotten, one also needs to adjust the header (it's easy).

Check my post here: https://www.biostars.org/p/9463791/#9467359

Comment: You're very welcome, @DavidStreuli. If one of the answers here solved your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](//bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the checkmark on the left. That is the best way to express your thanks on the Stack Exchange sites. Feel very fre to wait for a better answer, no need to accept mine now, I just wanted to let you know how the site works.